# Вывод таблицы из базы данных при помощи скрипта на Python

Tags: python, sql

В изучении Python и SQL я начинающий. Использую Linux.

Проблема: при попытке вывести на экран таблицу из базы данных компилятор сообщает, что это не база данных.

Однако! С помощью mariaDB все прекрасно в терминале выводится.

```
import sqlite3
import os.path


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("/home/user/newDB.sql"))
db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "newDB.sql")
with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT *FROM TableName")
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    print(results)
conn.close()
```

ОШИБКА:

> ```
> cursor.execute("SELECT *FROM Students")
> sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is not a database
> ```

В чем проблема? Будьте добры советом!

Comment: ошибка говорит вам о том, что файл по пути `db_path` не является файлом базы данных формата SQLite

Comment: И ещё между звездой и FROM должен быть пробел.

Comment: MaxU, а как переконвертировать файл .sql в формат SQLite?

Comment: @Enoch, думаю стоит открыть новый вопрос об этом...

Comment: У sqlite файл базы данных бинарного типа, а у вас в `.sql ` скорее всего не база находится а просто команды на языке sql (текстовый вид). Тогда,. вам сначала нужно открывать файл базы данных (указав другой путь например `newDB.sqlite`), после открыть скриптом файл `.sql` выгрузить оттуда команды sql и прогнав в `cursor.execute`

Comment: [Руководство](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python) по написанию скрипта на Python для работы с СУБД MySQL